# Form POST arrays: IIS vs Apache

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, apache

During some testing I discovered that on an Apache server form POST arrays needed to be different than those on an IIS server. Eg.

Apache:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="asd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="a[]" value="cvbcv" />
    <input type="submit" name="b" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

IIS using MVC3 Framework:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="asd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="cvbcv" />
    <input type="submit" name="b" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Both give the same result with an array called `a` of length 2.
At what point during the stack is this evaluated? Webserver, browser, etc.

Note: Using the opposite notation on each server fails to produce the array.

Comment: Weird. The latter is definitely wrong in my understanding.. although I'm not sure at which level this is defined, so maybe it's just another interpretation of a hazy spec

Comment: It works that way by design. Can you expand your question beyond "what gives"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a browser issue. I just tried this code in IE 9 and Chrome.

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Index", "Default")" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="vals[]" value="1"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="vals[]" value="2"/>
 <input type="submit" name="button" value="Go" />
</form>
```

And the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string button, string[] vals)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

In Chrome, **vals** was an array of length 1, with the only value being `1`

In IE9, **vals** was `null`

Comment: still - with MVC this isn't the recommended format, you still need array indexes, so the source code should be changed anyways to fit with what mvc accepts imho

Answer (score 1):

MVC definitely supports arrays, however you should specify [0], [1], [2]
This is a function of the web server and development language.
They may both parse separately.
PHP parses differently it seems than ASP.NET, but if you use 'opposite' notation you should really have the numbers so MVC at this point builds the model back properly (assuming you are using MVC model binding - which in that case its a function of MVC).

So to answer the question, its a function of the processing platform usually beyond the server from where you care about it. If you are referencing headers directly thats one thing, if not then its the platform language/technology (ie asp.net or php)

It should not be the browser.